# Where is this half buried Armenian church or monastery?

Tags: identify-this, locate-this, armenia, architecture, landmarks

While browsing Wikipedia and the Internet about some damaged Armenian churches in Tbilisi Georgia I came across an amazing photo (but I know this one is not in Tbilisi).

[This link is to the Armenian language web page with **the original picture** I found but could not include for copyright reasons.](http://www.hraparak.am/2011/04/06/im-khelar-hrashq/)

This is a photo I was able to find on WikiMedia Commons only **after mouviciel's answer came in**:
[image: Haghpat Monastery]

Unless my eyes are playing tricks on me it seems to be a half buried Armenian monastery, still intact but with beautiful green lawn growing on the mounds which conceal some of it!

**Where is it? What's it called? Is it really partially buried? Can I visit it?**

Comment: You're not one for easy questions :)

Comment: Some are not so hard d-; But I have a couple of Armenian friends so let me Facebook it...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Google on "half-buried armenian monastery" gives WikiTravel page on [Northern Armenia](http://wikitravel.org/en/Northern_Armenia). There I found [Haghpat Monastery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haghpat_Monastery). Google images confirms.

Comment: Great find! I did lots of Googling for half-buried monasteries and didn't spot it.

Comment: Actually, the search words were "half-buried armenian monastery". I edit my answer.

Comment: I thought I was being an expert with "half OR partially buried armenian monastery" d-;

Answer (score 11):

Haghpat monastery located in the north of Armenia.

Answer (score 8):

If you go to http://images.google.com, then click on the camera icon in the right of the search box, you can enter the url of an image or upload one to search with it. Using this you can usually find the answer in 2 seconds. It gives [this page](http://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi%3aAMhZZisqeI8ApGwQgF2BgQzWhAM4APFrExGxkxsMllwBwns03FfZfAwoln0g32q3GrT99wpmevW-2RZ0Y87tpTmPiwf9_1yj4CuVlR15ZBbSPL42KB3ONClNLAxi2RK93QqOaJkj7VverDUEf9ZuWlHuqw44b_163iGIYBpHcsbVwnn5xrBUuiHPr9yP7ALfw_1XVK-OT_1HSnbqB6Nb1K04mmnK2JvZmxiSGKbL3A8UTP4iD0hH8aimXEiaUpblSYru3ahEA6ed73DVBIHOxrpkvv_1DoFfYI2e1j4vPcMWy9HKDi3nS5W4LlKz3UcGuJM2TuI5iQN5OGpt511Frr3-YJh9ggkOs-gXoqBIaV-Rw4uAD-fB6gzWzArdmB3Igkk7yij51KEpnWdQH4x5qaRuhDtvJVmGDu5RYMjsj1IhHcAdPNjrfSlqINy47hjKp1Yl8jNgfdUXPzzpH_1ROP5ME_18yvYDHCwgAMxmZpNvtBGH2oKbtLYsfMChZ5oUz3rPcWpYHl7Rdx7yQ4HFwhvPNkSyIb71wFQwp8QcTYpdNXyqoMJdr_1rn-HVFGnovIOCcpvDkiShkVV71qK7-gy1cEKt_1WCAqHzMoc7Xlmu6jmqsCIMm8UIblTUhKqboN2R3EEr_1SGwWju7YIk9rrNVOz0QfB_1BPnOqYk_1a5KpLQAPa2Xj0yylb6MYD0vXx7G3haVddt9wVhjJCspBSyC1TYfI3fqxki7D3ZwRLePau6V6WjkQxB-AawM2ZowvFNnm-302sJ1eb3Te1C9hac-ulj_1eUnzVqTiNMVHUipfV-q8afl2tHSmLu2XdJ0L-9tk1EfThnBJJLBA6yuSO9kEahj7MNlrwk0fcbGm0KiD9X7xlEfE4D573lwGvzJK3FpwcAHFiDxF5Mro2Ew3wluS-lu_13OAMcy5DstZn28174V7BhoR1XRAunopraMabNqITDaQYscabzdMy9R-hhNuDgR5j_1ypNkXdNPoYUPC3YF8PAA9S3em9UmO68DWik6HrOXbnO2iJMm1Y3ARWf4exXim_1drQRyLcyETasOc4BI8q9vdk8i1SUOEip9QIYnyLyT-Vf8CXg41yjEZ7TV--yaZ2q21HNsEwKFg0a25Bn-to7NWotRGbiEG3juUcfrZLtzTKQABOg5eAf4eTclSxgCKe8SKSbxaiHCkplQmGiN0OzC54BelFvHQxzIEUJyFmnPptcubrXWk4-wYw7rQcJacry7MWU_1U7nuElzeHjpfmlv7wR65Vws6cjtwovr6SQ7-M05VCRjejVOQvGr8X6NZp7PYJpYlp1WwZdDVCwFuIwZDALUJaOusNR1vmI0pffrvDKul4OLm0s4pcZ8AuzG&num=10&hl=en&bih=708&biw=1440), and tells you that it is the Haghpat Monastery.

Hopefully this will be helpful in the future, and to others.

Comment: Actually I did try that and it didn't work. You are trying it with the picture from WikiMedia Commons that I added after I got the name of the monastery from the first answer, and not [the original picture I couldn't use for copyright reasons](http://www.hraparak.am/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/7-ej-im-khelar-e1302078678542-400x249.jpg). A Google Image search with it returns wrong results but I can't paste the link in because new Google image links are too long for this comment box )-:

Comment: Downvoted because this is NOT an answer.

Comment: @ankur, I wasn't sure if I should add this, but the stackexchange sites are also for reference for other people I the future (to prevent many nearly identical questions) so this 'answer' can help the OP and any visitor find the answer themselves.

Comment: It could've been worded a bit differently to be a valid answer and it *is* a good tip. Just didn't actually turn out to work with the source image this time.

Comment: @hippietrail, wording isn't my strong point, once of thought of something I usually find it impossible to reword it. So please edit :)